# How to dual boot install Ubuntu 15 with Windows 10: No other operating system recognized

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 from the directions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

My machine is a Windows computer running Windows 10, which was upgraded from Windows 8.1 several months ago.

When I try to run the installer, after the "For best results page" I get the message:

`"This computer currently has no detected operating systems"`

which I did not see when I just installed Ubuntu from the same USB stick on my Windows 7 machine.

I have toyed around with all of the boot options in the BIOS such as:

- Having the computer boot in UEFI mode (default) (no change)
- Having the computer boot in "legacy os mode"

Finally, turning fast boot off made one difference.  Now, when tying to install I immediately get this message (before it asks about any partitioning): 
[image: error message]

clicking `try again` always fails, clicking `continue anyway` leads me to the screen where I selected where I am located but I am not sure I want to continue with that installation.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try turning off Secure boot in the BIOS

Comment: Yes, it is already turned off.

Comment: Secure Boot is *VERY* unlikely to cause problems past GRUB, and certainly not to generate errors once Ubuntu (even the Ubuntu installation medium) has started. Disabling the [Windows Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [Hibernate](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) features *might* help, though. It may also be necessary to use the [Something Else](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) installation option.

Comment: Also, if Windows is booting in EFI mode, ***DO NOT*** enable the BIOS/CSM/legacy support. Read [Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) and [my page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) for more on EFI-mode installations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybee you didn't shutdown your computer completely before installing your Windows 10?

You have to disable quick boot and you should shutdown your computer completely before you proceed with the installation.

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7418-shut-down-computer-windows-10-a.html

You should install your bootloader into mbr of your system disc (sda) and not under the root partition. If it is not installed in mbr, grub2 will not recognize the operating systems on your hard disk.

Another way which might eventually help you to solve the problem is to boot into your Windows 10 and install Easy-BCD 2.3. It will search for the operating systems on the hard drive and you should be able to choose which one to boot on Windows 10 start - if there is any Ubuntu boot loader installed anywhere on the hard drive (like boot loader in the root partition).

Fast boot should be / stay disabled.

Comment: Windows 10 has been installed and working fine for several months.

I am not sure which "system discs" and hard drives you mean?

My machine is a Windows 10 Desktop, with two hard drives. An SSD and a platter drive.  I am trying to install Ubuntu from a USB drive that was formatted prior to putting the installer on it.

Answer (score 0):

Only one hard drive is a system disc - the one that holds the system partition, and where W10 is installed. Another drive is a data partition, I supose.

In Ubuntu, first hard drive will be called /sd**a**, second one /sd**b** and so on and the partitions are number that follows like sda**1**, sda**2**...

So, the boot loader must be installed in the drive itself (no numbers). If you should install in sda or sdb i can not say since I don't know where is your existing mbr installed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOtMOws7GJg

Comment: If by existing mbr you mean my Windows 10 operating system, it is installed on `sdb`. I really don't want to overwrite this.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to overwrite anything. You just need to add some space for Ubuntu.

The easiest way is to start with the live session (try without install or something like that). That way, Ubuntu will mount all existing partitions.

You can then repartition (from Gparted in Ubuntu) or also under Windows when you are in Windows session - it's completely up to you.

Ubuntu you install on that new partition or on the other drive. That's up to you.

Important is only where do you place your boot code, as I explained on the beginning.

You should als check that secure boot is disabled!

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Also, side note, you probably want to leave these as comments or edit your first answer rather than submitting three different answers.